# Improve for nested for loops to compare an array of words with one string (to see if it contains all of it's letters on it)

Tags: javascript

Newbie here.
So, I am solving everyday challenge from [Advent.js](https://adventjs.dev/) and I would like to find a more advanced way to do the same.

Today challenge is about to compare every word in an array with another one, to see if it has the letters on it. I don't know if I'm making my self clear, to be sure, please read the following:

**The instructions:**
*In Santa's workshop, the elves have a gift list they wish to make and a limited set of materials. Gifts are strings of text and materials are characters. Your task is to write a function that, given a list of gifts and the available materials, returns a list of the gifts that can be made. A gift can be made if we have all the necessary materials to make it.
*

**This is my code: **

```
function manufacture(gifts, materials) {
  // Code here
  const result = [];

  for(let i=0; i < gifts.length; i++) {
    for(let j=0; j < gifts[i].length; j++) {
        if (materials.includes(gifts[i][j])) {
          if(j === gifts[i].length -1) {
            result.push(gifts[i]);
          }
        } else {
          j = gifts[i].length;
        }
    }
     if (i === gifts.length -1) {
      return result;
    }
  }
  return [];
}
```

Thank you in advanced :)

My code worked, only failed 1 secret test

(Why aren't they public? Secret tests are designed so they cannot be solved with a solution that only passes the tests. If you fail a secret test, it is because your solution is not valid for the problem posed in all cases.)

I'm looking to improve and learn new ways to do things.

Comment: btw, why `j = gifts[i].length;`? a simple `break;` would work better than to change the index behind the length. and why do you check for the last loop of `i`? you could simply return `result` at the end of the function. it is either empty or has some gifts in it.

Comment: your code works at *advent.js*, actually.

Comment: As I say at the end of the post, it works, I'm just looking for ways to improve it if there are. The changes you suggest are very nice, thank you!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Here's an alternative approach using JavaScript's Array.prototype.every() method, which tests whether all elements in the array pass the provided function. It makes the code more readable and concise:

```
function manufacture(gifts, materials) {
  return gifts.filter(gift => {
    // Create a copy of materials for each gift
    let availableMaterials = materials;

    // Check if every character in the gift is available in materials
    return gift.split('').every(char => {
      if (availableMaterials.includes(char)) {
        // Remove the used character from available materials
        availableMaterials = availableMaterials.replace(char, '');
        return true;
      }
      return false;
    });
  });
}
```

In this implementation, for each gift, i check if every character (char) in the gift is present in the materials. If it is, i remove that character from availableMaterials to account for its usage.

The filter() method then collects only those gifts for which every() returns true, meaning all characters were found in the materials.

Comment: Actually, this code fails two tests in adventjs, I think the failure is that it should return all the gifts that have available materials to construct them.
You can check it out here and try it: https://adventjs.dev/es/challenges/2023/2
I found this solution that I found very satisfying:

function manufacture(gifts, materials) {
  return gifts.filter(g => {
    const x = [...new Set(...[g + materials])]

    return x.length == materials.length
  })
}

Comment: Also, after considerating, I think this is more appropiate for Coding Review than for Stack Overlow, because the code it was already working I just wanted to find other solutions. Thanks anyway